# Recalculating Excel Spreadsheets using 'formulas' library

Tags: excel, formula, openpyxl

**Preamble**: I have an Excel spreadsheet file that contains multiple worksheets.  I have created a utility using `Python 3.6` that reads a particular worksheet from the file into memory using `Pandas`, manipulates the data and then writes the results back to the Excel file using `OpenPyXL`.  The reason I use `OpenPyXL` to write the changes away is because the worksheet that I read-in contains data referenced through formula from other worksheets (so I have to trace my way back to find the original cells to update).

**My problem**:
Once I've written the data away using `OpenPyXL`, I can no longer re-read the worksheet again until I have recalculated the sheet and, until recently I could only do this using either Excel or `XLWings`.
However, I've found an Excel library for Python called `'formulas'` (https://pypi.org/project/formulas/) that claims to recalculate Excel spreadsheets without the need for Excel being installed and this is an excellent proposition as I then don't need to have Excel installed on my file servers where the `Python` code runs.

I've tried using the library and followed the documentation's example to recalculate the entire spreadsheet but this is taking an incredibly long time to recalculate (its been running whilst I typed this which is about 30 minutes and its still going).  I can't see from the library's documentation how to load and recalculate just a particular worksheet which I figure would be a lot quicker that trying to recalculate the entire file.

**My question**: Does anyone know how to use the formulas library for Excel and to read just a particular worksheet by name into memory, recalculate it and then write the worksheet back to the existing file whilst preserving the other worksheets that are already there i.e. I don't want to accidentally delete the other worksheets.

Comment: Use OpenOffice or LibreOffice in headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing Office on to the servers and using XLWings to drive the recalc process